# How to plot the horizontal bar graph in the given sequence of a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, matplotlib, bar-chart

I have the following dict in **Python 2.7**:

```
packetsNeeded = {
'Hydrogen': 142,
'Helium': 122,
'Lithium': 135,
'Boron': 145,
'Beryllium': 135,
'Nitrogen': 171,
'Neon': 141,
'Oxygen': 134,
'Carbon': 239,
'Florine': 134
}
```

I have written a script where I draw a horizontal bar graph of the Packets needed versus the Keys of the dict.

The code is simple and as follows:

```
from pylab import *

pos = arange(10)+.5

barh(pos, packetsNeeded.values(), align = 'center', color = 'green')
yticks(pos, (packetsNeeded.keys()))

for i, v in enumerate(packetsNeeded.values()):
    text(v + 3, i + .25, str(v), fontweight = 'bold', fontsize = '15')
xlim(0, 300)


grid(True)

show()
```

the Output is super nice and awesome:

[image: My Horizonatal Bar Graph]

#### Problem

How can I plot the `yticks` exactly mentioned as the key sequence in `packetsNeeded` dict? As you can see the first graph entry is `Beryllium: 135` as opposed to `Hydrogen: 142` in the `packetsNeeded` dict.

Also how is the sorting happening in the graph? I haven't mentioned any sorting in general anywhere in the code?

Comment: It upsets me a little that they're not in periodic table order in your dictionary.

Comment: @Tim Haha actually these are just names of Devices on a network. Ease of usability though.

Comment: And I think that the answer may be that dictionaries are not ordered in memory.

Comment: okay let me try it with a list, should it work or a Tuple is better?

Comment: Try with a list yes. A list of lists or of tuples should work

Comment: no it wont because `dict.keys()` anyways returns a list! hence `packetsNeeded.keys()` is already a list which is passed!

Comment: But there is no ordering to `dict.keys` because there is no ordering to any `dict`. Convert the dict into  a list of tupes, then pass `[i[0] for i in list]` as `dict.keys` and `[i[1] for i in list]` as `dict.values`.

Comment: Thanlks for the tips @Tim posted the answer. List of Tuples works like a charm..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Tim for suggestion of collecting data as a *List of Tuples* since

> that the answer may be that dictionaries are not ordered in memory

The collected data was now represented as a **List of Tuples**:

```
from pylab import *

## List of Tuples much better than dicts since dicts are not arranged
## in memory
packetsNeeded = [
    ('Hydrogen', 142),
    ('Helium', 122),
    ('Lithium', 135),
    ('Boron', 145),
    ('Beryllium', 135),
    ('Nitrogen', 171),
    ('Neon', 141),
    ('Oxygen', 134),
    ('Carbon', 239),
    ('Florine', 134)
]
```

Created some list comprehensions to seperate the values and names:

```
## List Comprehensions for Names and Values

names = [packetsNeeded[item][0] for item in range(len(packetsNeeded))]
values = [packetsNeeded[item][1] for item in range(len(packetsNeeded))]
```

rest of the code for plotting the Horizontal bar plot

```
pos = arange(10)+.5

barh(pos, values, align = 'center', color = 'green')
yticks(pos,(names))

for i, v in enumerate(values):
    text(v + 3, i + .25, str(v), fontweight = 'bold', fontsize = '15')
xlim(0, 300)

title('Number of Packets Needed by Each TWIN node in Multihop')
xlabel('Number of Droplets Needed')
ylabel('Name of TWIN nodes')
grid(True)

show()
```

#### Output

[image: Arranged data now on graph]